# Is there a way to install L2TP and OpenVPN on one machine and bridge between both VPNs?

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, bridge, openvpn

I am trying to install both OpenSwan-L2TP and OpenVPN on a Debian server and bridge between both server, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I expect it is possible; you'll probably want to fill out this question with `ip addr show` and `ip route show` and how you've tried to bridge the two together, before the good folks at [sf] can really help much. In the meantime, I suggest skimming the [LARTC](http://lartc.org/lartc.html) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am not one hundred percent sure that my answer is the most effective solution but apparently in both L2TP and and OpenVPN are on the same subnet client connected from both sides can communicate.

For example OpenVPN 10.1.2.1 - 10.1.2.63
And L2TP is on 10.1.2.64 - 10.1.2.254